# ListView Populating using Custom Class

Tags: android, listview

I am writing code for an Android application. I have a class called Categories, which has an ID and a name. I have saved the data into a SQLite Database and when I read all rows from the database, i have saved them into a List type list.

Now, how do I populate the listview to show my ID and category on the Listview.

P.S. I have a Listview in a Linear Layout and there is a header section on the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below ListAdapter for your listView
`ListAdapter.java`

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


private LayoutInflater myInflater;
private List<YOURDATATYPE> list;

public ListAdapter(Context context) {
    myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}

public void setData(List<YOURDATATYPE> list) {
    this.list = list;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;        

    convertView     = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    holder          = new ViewHolder();
    holder.id   = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);
    holder.category     = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category);

    convertView.setTag(holder);


    holder.id.setText(list.get(position).id);
    holder.category.setText(list.get(position).category);



    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView id;
    TextView category ;

}

}
```

in your ListActivity in OnCreate()

```
adapter   = new ListAdapter();

listView = getListView();
adapter.setData(YOUR LIST FROM DATABASE);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```